# using jQuery to set the content in tinyMCE when data comes from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, tinymce

I have a dropdown menu, on change of this, I need to set the content in the tinyMCE editor, I need to figure out how do I compare the selected option of dropdown and the xml tag, so that I can set the value.

here is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/S6Eqq/25/

Not sure if there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps you, you should get the value of your dropdown box like:

```
value = $('#country option:selected').val();
```

And your code...

```
var xml = '<xmlroot><nodes><id>US</id><desc>I am in the USA Description</desc></nodes><nodes><id>FR</id><desc>I am in the French Description</desc></nodes><nodes><id>ES</id><desc>I am in the Spain Description</desc></nodes></xmlroot>';


$(function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode:'textareas'
    });

    $("#country").change(function() {
       loadText();
    });

    function loadText() {
        //In this example you fetch them from the var xml. Later on you can fetch them through a get() function.
        //$.get('file.xml',{}, function(xml) {
         var value = $("#country option:selected").val();
            $('nodes',xml).each(function() {
                //Get id of selected XML node
                id = $(this).find("id").text();
                //Get description of selected XML node
                desc = $(this).find("desc").text();
                if (value != "") {
                   if (id.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) {
                       tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(desc);
                   }
                }
            });

        //});
    }
});
```

So basically you don't need to fetch the value when the `change()` event of the dropdown box is triggered.

You can simply access the selected value in your `function loadText()` method by making use of `$('#country option:selected').val();`.

So:

```
var value = $('#country option:selected').val();
$.get('file.xml',{}, function(xml) {
  $('nodes',xml).each(function() {
     id = $(this).find("id").text();
     desc = $(this).find("desc").text();
     if (id.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) { 
        tinyMCE.activateEditor.setContent(desc);
     }
  });
});
```

Note that you were getting the `coun` and `description` attribute of your XML, while these don't exist. You defined them as `id` and `desc` in your variable.

Secondly you never trigger your `$.get()` method. So I did this by putting this into the `function loadText() { ... }` which I trigger when the country selectbox changes.

See the functioning example here: http://jsfiddle.net/S6Eqq/32/

Comment: I doesn't work at all. though it doesn't report any errors in firebug, but I guess our logic in not proper. sorry for delayed response

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also actually did the same thing though I didn't had the function. The problem was that I was using tinyMCE.activeEditor(desc); instead I should have tinyMCE.activateEditor.setContent(desc); I really appreciate your help

Comment: But how do I resolve this error, when I select the first option of dropdown, which says Please select:
if (id.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) {...

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. I accidentally wrote `var value = $("#country option:not(:first):selected").val();`